# How to draw asterisks (*) line on the screen?

Tags: java, printing, println

How can I draw a horizontal line using around 50 asterisks `*` and using a for loop? When I tried to do this, the result was a 50 asterisk listed vertically (instead of horizontally).

```
public void drawAstline() {
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
         System.out.println("*"); 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: show us your attempts

Comment: Please format your post, asterisks are used to highlight text. Format them as code.

Comment: public void drawAstline() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   System.out.println("*");
  }
 }}

Comment: what did u use to print * ?

Comment: I used sytem.out.println("*"); inside a for loop for(int x=0,x<50,x++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `System.out.print('*')` instead of `System.out.println('*')`.

```
 System.out.println('*'); => System.out.print('*'); System.out.print('\n');
```

For your case, the output looks like `*\n*\n*\n*\n*\n`, where `\n` is an escape sequence that inserts a newline in the text at this point. `print('*')` allows avoiding that and the output will look like `*****`.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but could you elaborate it a bit more for the OP?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner for comparison:

```
System.out.println(new String(new char[50]).replace('\0', '*'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal Line :

```
for(int i=0; i<50; i++) 
   System.out.print("*");
System.out.println();
```

Vertical Line :

```
for(int i=0; i<50; i++) 
    System.out.println("*");
```

Because :

`System.out.println("*")` is same as :  `System.out.print("*\n")`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0;i < 50; i++)
{
   System.out.print('*');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try below one

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
System.out.print("*");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this script:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i <50; i++) 
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("For test");
    }
```

Let me know if this is what you want. The output should be this:
    **************************************************

For test

Comment: mark your post as answered and maybe give a + for the answers you used. it helps the community.. glad i could help ;)